# I wished to check if an input is in the string and then print the output

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I intended to let the program check if the input matches with any character in a str and then print out the result, the player input and the underscores in the correct places. This is my test code so far:

```
astring = "apple"
bstring = "_ " * 5
print(bstring)
my_input = input("enter a letter")

for i, n in enumerate(astring):
    if my_input == i:
        bstring[n] = my_input
    else:
        i = i + 1

print(bstring)
```

However, only the underscores are being printed out. Can anyone help me?

Comment: just wrong use of i and n and you can't assign value in string so convert into list to assign it.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you should be checking to see if the letter at your current index of your string is the same as the letter at the current index of your input string, to do this you can use:

```
if i < len(my_input) and my_input[i] == n:
```

Also, strings in Python are immutable, and so you can't change them via index. Instead, use an array of `_`, so that you can change what is at a particular index. Then, at the end, join each element in your list by a space.

Lastly, there is no need to increment `i`, as this is done for you by your `for` loop:

```
astring='apple'
bstring=['_']*len(astring)

print(bstring)

my_input = input('enter a letter')

for i,n in enumerate(astring):
    if i < len(my_input) and my_input[i] == n:
        bstring[i] = n

print(' '.join(bstring))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,n in enumerate(astring):
```

'i' is the index, 'n' is the character. You have it the other way around in 'if'.

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you

```
astring='apple'

bstring=["_" for i in range(len(astring))]
print(bstring)
my_input=input('enter a letter')

for i,n in enumerate(astring):
        if my_input==n:
                bstring[i]=my_input
        else:
                i=i+1

print(*bstring)
```